# Multiple Keywords in textfield or textView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I have to show keywords having a cross button in a textfield or textView. I am trying to get data from server that is keyword names that i want to show in a single line horizontally with a cross button on each keyword and can be disappear as soon as we hit on cross button. Any Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an equivalent of the Cocoa `NSTokenField` (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTokenField_Class/).

You should have a look to Cocoa Controls to find one that can suits you (https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=tokenfield).

Comment: This is not in swift. Can i get this in swift.